# How to update the nth row in a SQL database table?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I update only the nth row from a table?

To update the second row for example, i tried using UPDATE and LIMIT, but it is giving me an error.

```
 UPDATE database_table
 SET field = 'new_value'
 LIMIT 0, 1
```

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Why not just refer to it by it's primary key?

Comment: It is a option, but I will need to change a lot in my code to work that way. If there was no other option I will do this way.

Comment: nth row is relative. You don't know how the table will be sorted unless you specify it

Comment: It is sorted by the time it was added

Comment: No it's not.  It just looks like it is.  When you retrieve rows from it, they'll *probably* be in that order.  RDBMS's don't generally guarantee that though.  If you want an order, you need to specify it.  Referring to the `nth` row doesn't make sense, unless you explicitly mention an ordering.

Comment: Thanks @Gerrat, i thought it was always that way. I will think in a way to order it by the date is was added (probably a column with that value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a primary key and a column you'd like to order by (to get the nth row), you could do something like:

```
UPDATE database_table
SET field = 'new_value' 
WHERE primary_key IN (
    SELECT primary_key
    FROM database_table
    ORDER BY some_date_column 
    LIMIT n - 1, 1
)
```

**Edit:**  I should probably add a caveat.  This answer might be technically correct, but you're likely wrong to use it.  I can't imagine too many scenarios where you'd actually want to update the `nth` row of a table.  You should generally only be updating tables based on primary keys.  Updating the nth row will likely break your app if multiple users (or even multiple sessions with the same user) are using it at the same time.

The *real* answer is you should probably change your code to update based on primary key.

Comment: I am using this code to an application that only I am going to use, so it is going to work. But i will start changing my code to the to use a primary key. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -2):

You would need some sort of id, and then do something like this:

```
UPDATE database_table SET field = 'new_value' WHERE id = 2
```